# Adding difference of pair of numbers in list using map/reduce

Tags: python, list, functional-programming, reduce

I am practicing exercises for functional programming concepts using python. I came across this problem. I have tried a lot and couldn't find a solution using functional programming constructs like map/reduce, closures.

Problem: Given a list of numbers

```
list = [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3]
```

Find sum of difference in each pair using Map/Reduce or any functional programming concepts e.g

```
[[10 -9] + [8 - 7] + [6 -5] + [4 - 3]] = 4
```

For me tricky part is isolating pairs using map/reduce/recursion/closure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recursive relationship you are looking for is

```
f([4, 3, 2, 1]) = 4 - 3 + 2 - 1 = 4 - (3 - 2 + 1) = 4 - f([3, 2, 1])
```

Comment: Could you help me how this answers? Please , i am not the downvoter!

Comment: @Sislam Its a beautiful function as in functional programming. Can be implemented in any language.

Answer (score 2):

One of the mantras followed by many functional programmers is the following:

- Data should be organized into data structures that mirror the processing you want to perform on it

Applying this to your question, you're running into a simple problem: the list data structure doesn't encode in any way the relationship between the pairs that you want to operate on.  So `map`/`reduce` operations, since they work on the structure of lists, don't have any natural visibility into the pairs!  This means you're "swimming against the current" of these operations, so to speak.

So the first step should be to organize the data as a list or stream of *pairs*:

```
pairs = [(10, 9), (8, 7), (6, 5), (4, 3)]
```

Now *after* you've done this, it's trivial to use `map` to take the difference of the elements of each pair.  So basically I'm telling you to split the problem into two easier subproblems:

1. Write a function that groups lists into pairs like that.
2. Use `map` to compute the difference of each pair.

And the hint I'll give is that neither `map` nor `reduce` is particularly useful for step #1.

Answer (score 1):

using itertools.starmap:

```
l = [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3]

from operator import  sub
from itertools import starmap

print(sum(starmap(sub, zip(*[iter(l)] * 2))))
4
```

Or just a lambda:

```
print(sum(map(lambda x: sub(*x), zip(*[iter(l)] * 2))))
```

Or range and itemgetter:

```
from operator import itemgetter as itgt

print(sum(itgt(*range(0, len(l), 2))(l)) - sum(itgt(*range(1, len(l), 2))(l)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another try may be isolating pairs-You may need to sort the list beforehand

```
>>>import operator
>>>l=[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3]
>>>d= zip(l,l[1:])
>>>w=[d[i] for i in range(0,len(d),2)]#isolate pairs i.e. [(10, 9), (8, 7), (6, 5), (4, 3)]
>>>reduce(operator.add,[reduce(operator.sub,i) for i in w])
>>>4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in simple way.

```
l = [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3]
reduce(lambda x, y : y - x, l) * -1
```